# How can I put a div block below another lined up vertically when they are touch and are on the same line?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is the html and css code:

HTML:

```
<body>
  <div id="box1"></div>
  <div id="box2"></div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#box1 {
width: 500px;
height: 250px;
background-color: #75A9F9;
margin-top: 100px;
border-radius: 5px;
display: block;
float: left;
margin-left: 100px;
}

#box2 {
width: 500px;
height: 250px;
background-color: #75A9F9;
margin-top: 100px;
border-radius: 5px;
display: block;
float: right;
margin-right: 100px;
}
```

So this shows two blocks on the same horizontal line.  When I minimize the browser window by dragging the window to the left, it gets to the point where the two divs touch.

Once they touch, the one on the right goes UNDER the one on the left, but not vertically aligned.  Like this:
[right after touch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5eC5V.png)

My question is, how can I make it so that when the boxes touch, the right div goes DIRECTLY underneath the left div and stays until I arrange the window width big enough.  I want it to stay like this when they touch:
[want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKaKJ.png)

I couldn't find a bootstrap doc for this.  I want to use the two boxes to contain a dropdown select menu (I already know how to do this).  Let me know if you know of a bootstrap class that can suit my needs or a way to fix the code that I provided.  I'm open to suggestions in jQuery and Js.  Let me know if my question wasn't clear and I will be responding.  Thank you.

Comment: Have you thought about using @media queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good time to use **display: flex** see fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/cvnrwo13/5/

```
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div id="box1"></div>
    <div id="box2"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding: 0 100px 0 100px
}

#box1, #box2  {
  width: 500px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: #75A9F9;
  margin-top: 100px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For this, a good option would be to use a container with a specified `width` and `text-align: center`.  Then en lieu of floats, set the boxes to be `display:inline-block` elements.  As *inline elements*, they will then follow whatever text alignment their parent container specifies.

#### HTML

```
<body>
<div id="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
</body>
```

#### CSS

```
#container{
  text-align:center;
  width: 100%;
}
#container .box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #75A9F9;
  margin-top: 50px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qacnL2yr/